# Building ElementalX kernel on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Tags: kernel, compiling, android, gcc, arm

Attempting to build the **ElementalX kernel** for android on **Ubuntu 16.04(64 bit)**. I've downloaded the **kernel source files** and **NDK toolchain** folders and placed them in my home directory respectively. So i get to the final part which is compiling the kernel by running the following command `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi-`. It goes well for ten minutes until I'm faced with the following error:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: warning: unwinding may not work because EXIDX input section 58 of arch/arm/kernel/built-in.o is not in EXIDX output section
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: warning: unwinding may not work because EXIDX input section 9 of arch/arm/common/built-in.o is not in EXIDX output section
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: warning: unwinding may not work because EXIDX input section 6 of arch/arm/crypto/built-in.o is not in EXIDX output section
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: warning: unwinding may not work because EXIDX input section 24 of arch/arm/mach-msm/built-in.o is not in EXIDX output section
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: warning: unwinding may not work because EXIDX input section 40 of fs/built-in.o is not in EXIDX output section
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: warning: unwinding may not work because EXIDX input section 12 of crypto/built-in.o is not in EXIDX output section
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: warning: unwinding may not work because EXIDX input section 38 of block/built-in.o is not in EXIDX output section
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: warning: unwinding may not work because EXIDX input section 24 of lib/built-in.o is not in EXIDX output section
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: warning: unwinding may not work because EXIDX input section 33 of drivers/built-in.o is not in EXIDX output section
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: warning: unwinding may not work because EXIDX input section 6 of sound/built-in.o is not in EXIDX output section
arm-linux-androideabi-ld: warning: unwinding may not work because EXIDX input section 34 of net/built-in.o is not in EXIDX output section
drivers/built-in.o:mdss_fb.c:function mdss_set_rgb: error: undefined reference to 'kcal_ext_apply_values'
drivers/built-in.o:mdss_fb.c:function mdss_get_rgb: error: undefined reference to 'kcal_ext_show_values'
Makefile:786: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
```

Is anyone familiar with this kind of error? because I'm completely out of ideas and could such an error arise from the **toolchain** I'm using because before **NDK** i was using **linaro** and i was getting a completely different error about the file **"compiler-gcc5.h"** missing from my */include/linux* directory so do you reckon i should change the toolchain I'm using?

Comment: Hey, I noticed you edited this post and bumped the version from 15.04 to 16.04. Just a word of warning here -- if this is an attempt to bypass the EOL closure, you might not get answers that are remotely useful. If you are actually running 16.04 (or have confirmed that this problem exists in 16.04), feel free to disregard this comment.

Comment: @Kaz Wolfe Might i just add that this problem occurs regardless to how outdated or new Ubuntu is because it's related to the default kernel source files that are fetched from github.

Comment: Nevertheless I've provided the solution for anyone else who might be experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is solved by enabling KCAL in the **.config** file of your kernel source directory.

This can be achieved by changing the line

*# CONFIG_FB_MSM_MDSS_KCAL_CTRL*

to

*CONFIG_FB_MSM_MDSS_KCAL_CTRL=y*

All done problem solved :)